# How to use SSL on only half of the site?

Tags: security, ssl, joomla, https

My Site is half ecommerce store and half community blog. I've enabled SSL throughout the site, but the moment a community member posts a non-HTTPs link, the entire site becomes "insecure" according to the SSL certificate.

How do I require SSL on ONLY the ecommerce portion of the site?

I was told I may have to run my community Blog and ecommerce site as separate Joomla! installations. Surely there is a better way?

So that you can see the site it's [www.DetourJournal.com](http://www.DetourJournal.com)

Comment: You shouldn't get any mixed-content warning merely because you have some links to http sites. Only embedding http resources triggers such warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me why you would get warnings just because you have some links to http sites.

But I have a similar setup but I went with only enabling SSL for the eCommerce part only. Simple to do with this [plug-in](http://www.yireo.com/software/joomla-extensions/ssl-redirect).

Comment: I am definitely getting SSL Warnings when I, for example, create new blog post and link to a photo on another site. Specifically I lose my EV (green address bar) when those links are posted. Is this because the SSL Certificate is applied to the Entire domain, as opposed to being applied to specific pages?

Comment: @MichaelRomrell SSL certificates always apply to the entire domain. Use subdomains to keep things separate. But back to your question, if the blog is not SSL then you shouldn't have a problem. What does Firebug or Developer Tools tell you when you lose the EV?

Comment: Ahh! I could have SWORN I was losing the EV on all pages. However, today after uploading a quick HTTP image to the blog it blocked the EV only on the Blog pages. Is that normal?

Comment: The error message that Chrome gives me in place of the EV is "Your connection to www.detourjournal.com is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page.

The connection uses TLS 1.0.

The connection is encrypted using RC4_128, with SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

The connection does not use SSL compression."

Comment: After more testing I'm seeing that the non-http image that was uploaded to the blog, is causing seemingly random pages to not show the EV in the address bar. I'm seeing it throughout the site. and sometimes when the EV doesn't show up on a page you can just hit the 'back' and then the 'forward' button and and it will show! What other info can I give you that might help diagnose the problem?

Comment: @MichaelRomrell I looked at your site. (btw, I couldn't register it doesn't seem to work) I did look at the blog and it is complaining about youtube errors. You are mixing SSL throughout your site. So you have SSL everywhere but not every link is https. But I don't think this is what you are trying to achieve? I would use the plug-in I recommended to select what parts are SSL and what isn't. I don't see the problem with images you are outlining. Kind of hard to debug over comments. Use Chrome Developer Tools console tab. It tells you what is wrong.